# What is the better way when importing lodash?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lodash

I have two solutions for my React project:

1. `import { get } from 'lodash'`
2. `import get from 'lodash/get'`

Please help me choose a better solution to speed up page load.

Comment: import get from 'lodash/get' . go for the second one as it will import only get module, instead of complete lodash. tree shaking will also not happen if you have not configured your build creator(e.g webpack) for node modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import get from 'lodash/get';` is a much better and optimized way to import from commonsJs and `get.js` is separate file in the directory, so it's better to import only **2k** rather than complete **100k**

If you are using webpack 4,

```
import { get} from 'lodash-es';
```

`ES MODULES` are tree shakeable actually as `COMMONJS` modules aren't. so you should definitely use `lodash-es` ESM package.